# How to set exception language to English in Windows 10

Tags: .net, windows, localization

On my new laptop I get dotNET exception's message/ stack trace etc in Polish. I changed Windows 10 langauge to English, but problem still occurs.

```
public class MyClass { ... }
...
MyClass item = null;
item.IntProperty = 4; // NRE
```

Now I get NRE message in polish not in english. How and where can I configure exception details's language to English??

Answer (score -3):

You need to change the CurrentUICulture to en-US. Then it will come in English.

```
System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(el.DoLog);
t.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```